# How to suppress the extra output in visual studio code?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm using python 3.7 plugin in visual studio code for Windows. For some reason I get an extra output when debugging my code. How can I reconfigure the python plugin to hide this output?

```
PS C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Python_ex\Ch2>  ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'python' 'c:\Users\Aleksandr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.4.0\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher.py' 'c:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Python_ex\Ch2' '52829' '34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14' 'RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput' 'c:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Python_ex\Ch2\variables_finished.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the terminal command as that's how the debugger is launched. You may be able to configure your shell to somehow hide it, though I'm quite sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I suggest you get used to it, as it can show you what exactly runs behind. But if you really annoy with the outputs, I suggest you add "console": "internalConsole" setting in launch.json file.